# Create a complex number from magnitude and phase in C#

Tags: c#, complex-numbers

I have a method where I need to return a list of impedance measurements that are taken in magnitude and phase.  C# Complex struct seem like a natural fit; but, its constructor uses rectilinear rather then polar notation.  I see I can get phase; but, I don't see how I can set it.

Is there any other option than the following?  It seems pretty messy.

```
Complex value = new Complex(Mag*Math.Cos(Phase),Mag*Math.Sin(Phase))
```

Comment: Did you spot `Complex.FromPolarCoordinates` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex.frompolarcoordinates?view=netcore-3.1 ?

Comment: I did not.  I looked though the list a couple of times an my brain must have filtered it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sdgfsdh indicates in their comment, use [`FromPolarCoordinates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex.frompolarcoordinates?view=netcore-3.1):

```cs
Complex value = Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(Mag, Phase);
```